# Is there an AngularJS ORM

Tags: angularjs, bacon.js

I came a across the following article while considering adding bacon.js and AngularJS:

https://github.com/ProLoser/AngularJS-ORM

But I could not find any other resources that would encourage (or discourage) the use of bacon.js in angularJs.

So I'm looking for some other resources on the subject? Does anyone have use the concept proposed by Dean Sofer? Does it work the magic promise?

Has anyone use the concept used in the video?

Answer (score 4):

Sure this link can help you https://github.com/lauripiispanen/angular-bacon. Also I have my work with angularjs and bacon together https://github.com/xgrommx/angular-bacon-bridge.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Have you tried binding bacon.js to angularjs? What were the benefices?